# how to query a http request from a vc++ project

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, networking

I am writing a sample program to get a file from some site.
but it is replying me file not found errors,i dont know how to make an http header.
anyone help me in writing http headers.

AND i am trying to print the ip in this way(printf("%s\n",ptr->ai_addr->sa_data);)
 but not getting it how to print ip address??,am i doing it right??

my code is:-

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "80"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    char *sendbuf = "GET / HTTP/1.1[CRLF] Host: www.espncricinfo.com[CRLF]Connection: close[CRLF]User-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.0.37 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)[CRLF]Accept-Encoding: gzip[CRLF]Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[CRLF]Cache-Control: no-cache[CRLF]Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3 \r\n";
    char buff[DEFAULT_BUFLEN],recvbuf[512]; 
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Validate the parameters
    if (argc != 1) {
        printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo("122.169.255.9",DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server

        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        printf("inside loop %s ",ptr->ai_addr->sa_data);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        printf("%d\n",ptr->ai_addrlen);
//      printf("%s\n",ptr->ai_addr->sa_family);
        printf("%s\n",ptr->ai_addr->sa_data);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("socket error\n");
            printf("failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    // Send an initial buffer
    char filepath[]="pakistan/content/current/story/517271.html";
    sprintf(buff,"GET %s\r\n",filepath);
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket,buff, (int)strlen(buff), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    } 

    do 
    {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        //if ( iResult > 0 ) printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
         if ( iResult > 0 )
         {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            printf("%s",recvbuf);
         }
         else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError()); 

    } while( iResult>0 );

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use Microsoft Windows functions, the HTTP functions in WinInet are a lot easier. See [HttpOpenRequest/HttpSendRequest/HttpQueryInfo/InternetReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384322.aspx#Downloading_resource)

Comment: thnx what you said is right its lot easier,and i used it and completed my work...:)

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting "File Not Found", it's because you're requesting a file that can't be found.

Perhaps try `"/pakistan/content/current/story/517271.html"`, with the leading slash.

And where's your `HTTP` protocol specifier?

Write:

```
GET path HTTP/1.0
```

(1.0 because you probably don't want to mess about with virtual hosts; 1.1 if you have to)

And why do you shutdown the socket before attempting to read from it...? I know you only shutdown the "send" pipe, but it still seems odd.

Perhaps you ought to use a pre-established library to do this for you.

---

The webserver at http://122.169.255.9/ doesn't appear to actually work. Perhaps test with a known-good server like http://www.google.com first.

Comment: "GET / HTTP/1.0 \r\n Host: www.espncricinfo.com \r\n Connection: close \r\n Accept-Encoding: gzip \r\n Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 \r\n Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3 \r\n";
...................this is my http header can you correct my wrongs plss

Comment: @abhinav: That's not what your question says.

Comment: @tomalak:now my problem is simplified,i just now changed http header to "GET / HTTP/1.0 \r\n"; and i am getting http response but when i send http request as "GET path HTTP/1.0\r\n",i am getting file not found and i am using 80.168.92.185 to connect to cricinfo......

Comment: @abhinav: When I go to `http://122.169.255.9/pakistan/content/current/story/517271.html` (or even just `http://122.169.255.9/`) in my web browser, I get an "invalid URL" error. I think you have larger issues. Perhaps try getting your code to work with `www.google.com` first.

Comment: @ tomalak.....sorry for editing inbetween but i posted in my above comment that i am using 80.168.92.185 IP now and can u please reply to my comment before this,am i specifiying my http request( "GET path HTTP/1.0\r\n") correctly??

Comment: @abhinav: All this back and forth appears to be wasting my time :(

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, use a library like [libcurl](http://curlpp.org/).

Comment: I just want to download 1 file everytime from the same url,so if i can specify the header its fine,i need help in creating my header..:)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tomalak Geret'kal

You'll want to use HTTP/1.0 unless you want to check for chunked content and more stuff HTTP 1.1 can throw at you.

Install Wireshark and log the requests. You'll see what is wrong.

I'm not aware of [CRLF] being automatically changed to \r\n

Comment: Oh, I see, he's edited his question and used a literal string `"[CRLF]"`. Lol.